# Hide items in a ListBox when ListBox is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When a standard ListBox is disabled, the elements in it are simply grayed out. They are still visible, despite not being clickable. I would like to know if it is possible, and if it is, how to hide these items when the ListBox is disabled. I do not want to remove the elements from the ItemSource or create a temp storage for them.

So far, I thought about changing the visibility of the ListBox but that gets rid of the entire thing (including the border lines).

Comment: how do you bind them ?

Comment: A simple solution is to have two listboxes. One full of items, the second empty in the same exact location. When you need to hide the items of the first set it to disabled/invisible and set the second to visible/disabled and viceversa

Comment: @Tigran I have an ObservableCollection full of strings that is bound to the ListBox ItemsSource in the XAML:
`ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}"`

Comment: @Steve - Look's like great minds think alike! Just curious, since I am new to SO, how come you added a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @MrB because I think it is preferable to add a bit of code in an answer. When I don't have time to code an example I just put the idea as a comment. (a personal point of view of course, your answer is perfectly acceptable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind `Visibility` of `ListBoxItem` to `IsEnabled` of `ListBox`

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add another ListBox to the form and when you disable the first listbox with the elements inside of it, hide it, and then display the other to the user which will essentially be an empty greyed out listbox.

Then when you enable the box back, hide the empty one and show the real one.

Hope this helps.